# BSOD when Booting cloned Windows 7 on USB

Tags: windows-7, bsod, usb-storage

The specific sequence of events is as follows:

1. I have Windows 7 installed on my laptop.
2. I used EaseUS Todo Backup and used the "Clone" operation and successfully cloned the Windows 7 from the C:\ to an external USB drive.
3. I used EasyBCD to create a BCD entry on the USB drive and called it "Backup Win7".
4. I boot my machine normally on my C:\ Windows 7 with no problem (to test).
5. I specify to boot from the USB drive on the same laptop, and it detects the "Backup Win7" entry and it starts booting.
6. Normally, Safe Mode, and Safe Mode with Command Prompt all give BSOD and I can't see what the error is because it immediately restarts. Every time.
7. I noticed in the Safe Mode with Command Prompt the last driver it tried to load is the classpnp.sys.
8. I renamed classpnp.sys to classpnp.bak. Still BSOD.
9. Similarly, I renamed cdrom.sys to cdrom.bak. Still BSOD
10. The BIOS doesn't have IDE choice -- just AHCI and ATA. Both give BSOD.

My guts say that since the only difference is the hard drive itself, the Backup Win7 doesn't know that the hard drive changed to USB.
How do I make it refresh that?

Comment: As a note, ATA is the IDE choice. The classpnp error is because your USB stick is actually a PNP device.

Comment: @Overmind -- so I should keep the classpnp.sys. But why is it failing at startup? Why doesn't it like the USB bootup?

Comment: Win7 doesn't support booting from USB (added first in Win8, called WinToGo).

Comment: W7 boots system comes in conflict with PNP devices, that why it won't work.